# How to get the number value in dropdown select and create element input textboxes from the value selected?

Tags: javascript, loops

Simple Question from a beginner/learner in JS.

How to get the number value in dropdown select and create element input textboxes from the value selected?

I have a select option with number values, I want to create a number of textboxes when select a number in the options.

For example: On the dropdown I select 8, so it need to output 8 texboxes.

my code below:

```
<select class="form-control" id="textboxes">
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
          </select>



  var textboxNumbers = document.getElementById("textboxes").value;

  var i;

  for(i=0; i<textboxNumbers; i++){

    var yourTextboxes = document.createElement("INPUT");
    yourTextboxes.setAttribute("type", "text");
    document.getElementById("balls").appendChild(yourTextboxes);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `value` in option and add `onchange` in select

```js
function changeValue(){
  var textboxNumbers = document.getElementById("textboxes").value;
  balls.innerHTML = '';
  var i;

  for(i=0; i<textboxNumbers; i++){

    var yourTextboxes = document.createElement("INPUT");
    yourTextboxes.setAttribute("type", "text");
    document.getElementById("balls").appendChild(yourTextboxes);
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="textboxes" onchange="changeValue()">
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select>

<div id="balls"></div>
```

Comment: There's no need for value.
"...The value of an option element is the value of the value content attribute, if there is one, or, **if there is not, the value of the element's text IDL attribute**"

Answer (score 0):

In your select-Tag you need a change event. The change event calls the addElements function with the `this` parameter (`this` contains the select element). In your function you can get the selected value with `selectElement.value`. Before adding elements `balls.innerHTML = ""` will empty your balls element.

```js
function addElements(selectElement) {
  var textboxNumbers = selectElement.value;
  var balls = document.getElementById("balls");

  balls.innerHTML = ""; //Empty "balls" element

  for (var i = 0; i < textboxNumbers; i++) {
    var yourTextboxes = document.createElement("INPUT");
    yourTextboxes.setAttribute("type", "text");
    balls.appendChild(yourTextboxes);
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" onchange="addElements(this)" id="textboxes">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
</select>

<div id="balls"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Create and call a function on change of the drop down.

```js
const balls = document.getElementById("balls")

function createTxtBox() {
  var textboxNumbers = document.getElementById("textboxes").value;
  var i;
  balls.innerHTML = ''; // remove previously created text box
  for (i = 0; i < textboxNumbers; i++) {
    var yourTextboxes = document.createElement("INPUT");
    yourTextboxes.setAttribute("type", "text");
    balls.appendChild(yourTextboxes);
  }


}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="textboxes" onchange='createTxtBox()'>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<div id='balls'></div>
```